# GridView sorting and paging Entity Framework with calculated field

Tags: entity-framework, gridview-sorting

I am paging and sorting a `GridView` which uses `ObjectDataSource`. The `ObjectDataSource` gets data from a List in my business layer, and this List is populated by an `IEnumerable<Type>` in my data layer which uses the Entity Framework.

The guts of the paging and sorting is done in the data layer, as follows:

```
var customers = (from c in entities.Customers
                      select c).OrderBy(sortParameter).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows));
```

As you can see, I am passing parameters from the `ObjectDataSource` to decide how any records need to be returned, and from which position, to control the paging and sorting.

This all works fine.

My problem is that I need to sort by a field that does not exist in the database table. It is a calculated field that is added in my business layer (the List). (This calculated field is a Customer name that is looked up in a DLL based on  `Customer ID` in my database).

I was hoping to keep the sorting and paging logic in the database layer, but cannot find a neat way to do this. Should I be paging and sorting in the business layer instead (this is a List). If so, can anyone give me some tips how I can add similar paging and sorting to my List that currently exists in my data layer. (i.e. I am only looking to return the rows from my database that are needed for the current page of the `GridView`).

Thanks for any help, and kindly let me know if I can explain this more clearly!

Comment: Do you want to order the small amount of currently visible rows or do you want to order all rows? Order all rows is the usual way and in that case you would need to populate the calculated field for all rows.

Comment: Yes, I think it would be all rows. I think that is what the LINQ in my above code sample is doing. I am not sure where to add the calculated field - i.e. in the business or data layer. If the former, I would need to move my paging and sorting to the business layer, which again, I am unsure about.

Comment: I have made some small changes to the above post, and hopefully made the question clearer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541592/paging-and-sorting-entity-framework-on-a-field-from-partial-class